# mongoid where query returns different count than actually using the enumerator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a rails application that uses mongo as the data store.  Mongo is configured with 3 query routers and 16 shards.  When I do something like:

```
count = Item.where(:confirmed => true).count
```

I get around 800K items.  However, when I run a batch to actually walk through the items, the count is substantially smaller:

```
batch_size = 10000
offset_count = 0
completed_count = 0

# prime the pump
q = Item.where(:confirmed => true).limit(batch_size).skip(offset_count * batch_size).to_a

while q.count > 0
  # do something
  completed_count += q.count
  offset_count += 1
  q = Item.where(:confirmed => true).limit(batch_size).skip(offset_count * batch_size).to_a
end

# here, completed count is << count (where "count" is the initial .where count)
```

Any idea what's going on here? Does mongo estimate the total count instead of computing it from the index?

FWIW, there is an index on items for :confirmed, and I reindexed before running this to make sure there was no index corruption.

Thanks for any help.
kevin

Comment: thanks for the reply, I tried adding sorting, no difference, still only getting about half of the item count returned in the first query.

Answer (score 0):

justa guess. but it seems to be the order of operation. try skip then limit.
it looks like you are limiting it by 1000 then skipping at first 0, then 1000, then 2000. skipping 2000 on a record set limited to 1000 will return 0. and halt at the test.

Comment: is it possible that the connection is hitting a subset of the full shard. the 800k result is running "Item.where" code once; while the other is running "Item.where" presumably many times potentially connecting to a dead shard, throwing exception or ?